# Converting HTML to XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got an interesting problem. I was asked to convert an existing HTML email I did to XSL. From what I've read online, XSL is just a stylesheet type for XML. Obviously, you can't use an external stylesheet for emails and have to do everything inline.

I really feel like this is not possible. Am I incorrect in my assumption? I'm not familiar with XSL in the slightest (nor XML). I think the person who requested it may be confusing XSL with XML.

Thank you!

Comment: From reading your question I think someone might be confusing XLS, XSL, XML. First thing would be to clarify the objective.

Comment: They simply asked for the XSL format of an HTML email since they are 'implementing new templates in their system.' When I saw the request, I was like "What? That doesn't seem like the right file format...." I believe you're right they are definitely confusing XSL and XML! I think HTML to XML is possible but not XSL since it's a stylesheet type.

Thank you for relieving the confusion in my brain. :)

Comment: well, they may be asking you to create an XSLT that can be used as a template to generate that email message, possibly substituting variables (think, mail merge)

Comment: And you can totally generate XSLT (which is *just* a specialized flavor of XML)

Comment: I have no idea how to go about doing that. I think this may be above my pay grade LOL
From what I've read so far it looks like you take an XML doc, combine it with an XSLT document, and you are given the result.

Comment: Well the people changed their mind and said 'HTML is fine' after their boss told them they need to change their system to HTML to match all of the other ones we have in use.